# Google App Engine and Git best practices

Tags: git, google-app-engine

I'm developing a small pet project on Google App Engine and I would like to keep the source code under source control using [github](http://www.github.com); this will allow a friend of mine to checkout and modify the sources.

I just have a `PetProject` directory with all the sources and the Google App Engine  development server pointing to that directory.

Is it correct to create a repo directly from PetProject directory or is it preferable to create a second directory mirroring  the develop `PetProject` directory?
 In the latter case, anytime my friend will release something new, I would need to <strike>pull</strike> fetch from Git copying the modified files to the develop `PetProject` directory.

If I decide to keep the repo inside the develop directory, skipping `.git` on Gae yaml is enough?

What are the best practices here?

Comment: You shouldn't need to explicitly tell App Engine to skip .git directories - if I recall correctly, it already skips dotfiles by default.

Comment: I recommend you the new "push to deploy" option in App Engine has a best practice to deploy your project. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/push-to-deploy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a git repo directly within your current PetProject directory.

One trick would be to clone your new (and empty) GitHub repo in a local directory, and then copy the `.git` subdirectory in your PetProject directory.
That way, you have a Git repo already connected to a remote GitHub upstream repo.

Modify your .gitignore file to exclude what you dont 'want to publish.
`git add -A` and then `git commit -m "first commit"`
And then push to your GitHub repo.

Note: instead of pulling from your git repo (which means merging immediately whatever has been pushed on the same branch), you might want to [fetch first, and then check what you could merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git).

---

As [Nick Johnson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12030/nick-johnson) comments though, GitHub has a [clear process to setup a remote](http://github.com/guides/setting-up-a-remote-repository-using-github-and-osx#remoterepo).

```
 git remote add github git@github.com:git_username/projectname.git
```

Comment: There's no need to use the workaround you suggest - github provides easy instructions on adding a remote repo to an existing local when creating a new github repository.