# How can I add current Eclipse project to git with EGit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have GAE project in my Eclipse and I want to add it to my local git repo, how can I do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since creating a [Git repo within a GAE project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2919517/google-app-engine-and-git-best-practices) is possible through command line, it is possible through Egit:
Follow that [Egit tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#respository):

For a new repo:

> Right click your project, select Team -> Share -> Git.
>   Select the proposed line and press "Create repository". Press finish

[image: egit repo creation dialog]

> Create the file "`.gitignore`" in your project with the following content.
>   All files / directories which apply to the pattern described in this file will be ignored

But you can also add it to an existing local repo by:

- making a special branch for your project in your local repo (with just the `.gitignore` file in it)
- clone it where your current project is
- add all your current project files in it
- import said Git repo into your workspace: See [4.2 Clone existing project](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#respository_checkoutproject).

---

[informatik01](https://stackoverflow.com/users/814702/informatik01) adds in the comment a link to a short article describing how to do it using the command line:
[Adding Eclipse Project to Git](http://linuxsagas.digitaleagle.net/2009/06/26/adding-eclipse-project-to-git/)

```
cd ~/workspace/my-project
git init .
```

Comment: @informatik01 good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.