# How to know the list of files changed when you do a fetch using git

Tags: git

How do you get to view the files which have changed, the following fetch / update command seems to fetching some data but I don't have a clear picture of what got changed in the last run.

```
c:\examples>git fetch
got fac9a16c714aaa993267269676980f6433430797
walk fac9a16c714aaa993267269676980f6433430797
got 8751f9c82175ca08d1d1a2549b24479a72b10d0f
got c3e210c5a0cb9316d9f67a31bc0adba622866d5e
got 43a1ac031d097952d607acc93f4e1524ec06cc46
walk 43a1ac031d097952d607acc93f4e1524ec06cc46
got 78012cec43abb804dc3db59024452b8dd98fac54
got 32e287698fdbacd09fe3bafd92bf62291cfef6aa
walk 32e287698fdbacd09fe3bafd92bf62291cfef6aa
got 9e022dd8f4e35c446504ea232566b590e299e975
got 35bce0fdc496a65697d3ca1e5010d9448476c00f
got 0749e58ec244915b98377bba44e869e28f678df0
got 6f3836ed45a0a89a171d384c8c2c08bf260b14e5
got 3191d7c953b6fd342b3008e166243610377eac38
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 git fetch && git log ..origin/master
```

is more precise. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git).

Answer (score 1):

A `git diff` will show you the difference between the files.