# Show new revisions in gitk after git pull

Tags: git, gitk

After I do `git pull`, I want to see the revisions I just fetched in `gitk`. How can I do this? I know I can see what revisions to use in the output of `git pull` and I can give them as a parameter to `gitk`, but I want to do this automatically.

(Actually, I don't need to see all the fetched revisions, those from the current branch are sufficient.)

I use `msysgit`'s `git bash`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try a command similar to the ones used in "[How can I see incoming commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git)"

```
git fetch && gitk ..origin/master
```

, using the `<rev>` part of the "`gitk [<option>…] [<revs>] [--] [<path>…]`" syntax.

```
<revs>
```

> Limit the revisions to show.
>   This can be either a single revision meaning show from the given revision and back, or it can be a range in the form "`<from>..<to>`" to show all revisions between `<from>` and back to `<to>`.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea, although I would extend that into `git fetch && gitk ..origin && git merge origin`.

Comment: You lost 23 points in the rep recalc you requested.  Sorry, I know that must be a crushing setback.  ;)

Comment: @Bill: I... I will somehow find it in me to go on and move forward. Thank you for your support in this difficult time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have a really complicated tree there doesn't seem to be any reason not to use `gitk --all &`, then when you have done a git pull just select update or reload in the gitk menu.

Comment: If I did this, I wouldn't be able to distinguish new revisions from the old ones easily.

Comment: Don’t use `git pull` then. Use `git fetch`, reload in `gitk`, run `git merge` manually.