# What is the git equivalent of of hg outgoing (hg out) or hg incoming (hg in)?

Tags: git, mercurial

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see incoming commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git)

What is the git equivalent of of "hg outgoing" or "hg incoming"?

In Mercurial, `hg outgoing` lists the changesets that are newer than what's on the server and will be sent if I were to do `hg push`. Same in reverse for `hg incoming` and `hg pull`.

Comment: What do `hg in` and `hg out` do?  That info would probably help get you an answer; most people don't use Mercurial.  :P

Comment: @cHao. Most people frustrate with Git when come from CVS/SVN ))

Comment: The worst flaw of Mercurial that it doesn't work with GitHub. =)

Comment: @techtonik but, now that the future is here, [hg-git](http://hg-git.github.io/)!

Comment: @binki, yes! And now it works with GitHub as expected. https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hg-git/issues/144/support-github-urls  =)

Comment: @techtonik I’m not sure I’d call `git@github.com:user/repo` a URL. I think the production for a URI scheme would prevent `@` from being in there…

Comment: @binki, GitHub calls them SSH URLs, so ask them if you want https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/

Answer (score 102, accepted):

If you want to list commits that are on branch `B` but not on branch `A`, do `git log A..B`.

If you want to list commits that are on your local branch `dev`, but not the the remote branch `origin/dev`, do:

```
git fetch origin             # Update origin/dev if needed
git log origin/dev..dev
```

If you want to list commits that are on the remote branch, but not on the local branch, simply do the converse:

```
git fetch origin             # Update origin/dev if needed
git log dev..origin/dev
```

Note: you might find it easier to compare branches graphically using `gitk origin origin/dev`

Comment: What if I want a list of commits that are in my repo, but not on the remote, regardless of branch?

Comment: @Jorn The [man page for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html) has an example section where you will find an example that does exactly that.   (If you don't find it, please submit this as a separate question as it is not related to the original question.)

Comment: @adl, hmm, `hg outgoing` shows all branches which is exactly what @Jorn is asking for. So, that would mean the answer is invalid for this question… or the answer doesn’t discuss how `hg push`’s default behavior is more like `git push --mirror` than `git push` ;-).

Comment: How do you do it without fetching? I don't want to mutate my local repository, I just want to see what would happen if I did a fetch, but without actually doing it.

Comment: Yes, you are all correct - this does not answer the question "what if I pull?" and "what if I push?" completely, but still - this is waaay better than nothing ;) This also has general utility for comparing branches (not only remote tracking ones).

Comment: So to answer the original question (which this answer doesn't). `hg outgoing` can be done in git via `git log --branches --not --remotes=origin`

Comment: I found this post by searching for *git equivalent of hg view*. It turns out `gitk` was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Michael why not post it as an answer instead? It's easier to see it then and we can upvote your more correct answer

Comment: @OZZIE I think the question was closed quite a while before I answered so wasn't able to unfortunately.