# Before calling git push, how do I know the how many files I am going to push?

Tags: git

I would like to know how many files I am going to push, which git command can do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7624790/what-is-the-git-equivalent-of-of-hg-outgoing-or-hg-incoming

Answer (score 0):

You'll always push all commits in the branch(es) you are pushing which do not exist on the remote side yet.

There is no easy way to determine the number of files added/modified by all those commits.