# Git diff between current and head

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two cloned versions of a repo (working copies) - say  A and B.  Now, in B, I made changes to file  `filename`, committed and pushed.  A is untouched. Now, before pulling in A, I want to see what new changes will a `pull` bring in.

I tried:

```
git diff
git diff HEAD
git diff HEAD:filename   filename
```

but none of them show the diffs (blank output). How to correctly view diff between local copy and head (I checked other answers, and my understanding of them is the above, but none of them seem to work).

Note: I have recently moved from svn to git. So the way I am thinking is: A & B are just copies of same "branch". Not sure if the understanding/terminology is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to fetch first, then you can look for the diffs:

```
cd A
git remote add B /path/to/B
git fetch B

git diff master B/master
```

You can see other diffs in "[How can I see incoming commits in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1331459/6309)"

---

> I have installed gitolite on a server. And there is a repo there, say `ProjectXYZ`.
>   Now, `A` and `B` are obtained on two different machines, using `git clone user@reposerver:ProjectXYZ.git`.

Then:

```
# on machine B
cd B/
git push -u origin master

# on machine A
cd A/
git fetch
git diff master origin/master
```

Comment: Hmm. A and B are on different machines.  And they both are copies of (sorry - have just switched from svn to git so some terminology may be wrong!) origin/master. I am not sure what `git remote add B /path/to/B` would do and infact how to specify it.

Comment: @WorkWise are both A and B cloned from a third repo, which can act as a reference?

Comment: Hmm - so basically I have installed `gitolite` on a server. And there is a repo   there, say  `ProjectXYZ`.   Now, A and B are obtained on two different machines, using  `git clone user@reposerver:ProjectXYZ.git`

Comment: @WorkWise then you can `git push` from `B`, and `git fetch` from `A` (no need to add any more remote). The `git diff` I mention in the answer will give you the diff you want.

Comment: I did `git fetch` in A. Then `git diff master origin/master` worked. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @VonC. I learned the new `fetch` command and my understanding of `cloned copies` and branches increased.