# How to reference remote repositories in a git alias?

Tags: git, github, version-control, alias

How can one reference a git alias to perform an operation on the equivalent tracking branch on a remote repository called "origin"? For example, if I am on branch "foo" of my local repo, and I want to run a command that normally defaults to my "origin/foo" branch, how can I do so?

Here is a concrete example:

I want to see the incoming commits from my "origin/foo" branch, and I am on my local "foo" branch. To do so, I would run `git fetch && git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit ..origin/foo`. Thus, I set up a `git incoming` alias as follows:

```
[alias]
    incoming = !git fetch && git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit ..@{u}
```

However, this alias is interpreted as `git fetch && git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit ..upstream/foo`, where the `@{u}` is a substitute for the equivalent branch on the upstream remote. I want to do the same command, but on the equivalent branch on the **origin** remote. How can I do this? I tried `@{o}`, but that doesn't work, and I cannot find this syntax anywhere in the git alias docs. I derived my answer from @sschuberth's comment in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git), but I have not found much documentation otherwise.

**Update**
I found a close solution, but it uses a bash argument instead of a git alias:

```
incoming = !git fetch && git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit ..$1
```

The disadvantage here is that I cannot leverage the auto-completion provided by git and it does not automatically compare my local branch against that of my remote `origin` repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that to the best of my knowledge [Git still does not properly support a "triangular" workflow](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/224604) where you pull from an "upstream" remote, apply your changes, and push to an "origin" remote (which is your fork of the upstream project). Junio, Git's maintainer, says

```
Note that even in a triangular workflow,  <at> {u} should still refer to
the place you integrate with, i.e. your "upstream", not to the place
you push to publish the result of your work.
```

You can only have one remote tracking branch per local branch, and that either is the corresponding branch in `upstream`, or the corresponding branch in `origin`. `@{u}` points to whatever is configured as the remote tracking branch, independent of whether semantically this is your upstream project or forked project. Confusingly, the Git docs refer to `@{u}` as being a shorthand for "upstream", but in fact it most of the time points to what usually is "origin".

Long story short, for `@{u}` to work like you want your need to change the remote tracking branch for your local branch `foo` from `upstream/foo` to `origin/foo` using `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/foo`.

*Edit:* If you're adventurous you could probably also try using [Felipe Contreras' fork of Git](http://felipec.github.io/git/) which adds [the concept of a "publish" tracking branch](https://felipec.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/git-triangular-workflows/).

Comment: Perfect answer for an imperfect feature in git :-) I ran `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/foo` and now I can use my alias as usual. I use `upstream` remotes as well, usually when branching from open-source projects, which made this more confusing as I usually push/pull with my `origin` remote. Manually setting my branch to my that of my `origin` remote fixes this