# How to see what files will be 'pulled' when I do a git pull

Tags: git, version-control, git-pull

I am on branch master and there are multiple users doing simultaneous pushes to the branch in the same repository.
Now I need to do a `git pull` but I am not sure what files will be pulled as I don't know what all files were pushed.

Is there a way to know exactly what files will be pulled or what changes will be made if I do a `git pull` before the actual pull/merge is done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331385/how-can-i-see-incoming-commits-in-git

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
git fetch && git log --name-only HEAD..@{u}
```