# EGit - how to see fetch history

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

Working in Eclipse with EGit. We have code on GitHub. My collaborator pushed changes to GitHub. I can see them on GitHub. When I try to do a fetch, EGit says everything is up to date. However, when I do a Synchronize Workspace on my local machine, it does not show the changes that are on GitHub. Someone suggested that perhaps the changes had already been fetched, which seems rather mysterious to me, but I want to check out that possibility. I cannot find any way, though, to show the fetches that have been done. Is there a way in EGit to see what has been fetched, short of merging it? Or failing that, a command line `git` command?

Comment: Check the ref log, see if head points to same commit as remote. `Window > Show View > Git > Ref Log`

Comment: This only shows the commits that I made, not the fetches

Comment: See [this answer to _How can I see incoming commits in git?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1336988/1744774) which mentions [`git whatchanged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-whatchanged) that's unfortunately not listed in [the Git Reference's TOC](https://git-scm.com/docs) :(.

Comment: git whatchanged just shows my commits. I don't want to see the commits. I know how to do that already. I want to see what was fetched.