# Are "Merge remote-tracking branch 'xxx/master'" commits a trouble for Pull Request?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, git-pull, git-commit

There is a Github repository [I have forked](https://github.com/C-Duv/AlerteLeboncoin) on which multiple commits where made afterwards.

I wanted these corrections to be part of my forked repository I might have merged them (but can't remember how) and I now have a commit named [*Merge remote-tracking branch 'blount/master'*](https://github.com/C-Duv/AlerteLeboncoin/commit/ec93dec3786a255f52ddfc1407220dd2d1222ff0).

Is it a problem for future pull requests I will make? Or will they have no incidence at all when the owner will accept my pull request?

I've found the [*Why am I merging “remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into develop”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406762/why-am-i-merging-remote-tracking-branch-origin-develop-into-develop) stackoverflow question which says how to avoid this situation, but not if existing *merge-commit* are a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This depends, generally, on whether or not a) the pull request can be automatically merged an b) (more importantly) whether the tests pass.

You can create an `upstream` remote that points to the original repository, then merge `upstream master` into `origin master` and it will be up to date.

You should do this first to preemptively solve any merge conflicts or unexpected breakages.