# Is git up a valid command?

Tags: git

Is there a command called `git up`. I have seen a few other posts where it is used. I am using git version 1.7.9.5 and I get following error when trying to use the command :

```
git: 'up' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Might you be referring to [this](https://github.com/aanand/git-up)?

Answer (score 4):

Those posts may be referring to [this tool](http://aanandprasad.com/git-up/), whose source code is [available here](https://github.com/aanand/git-up).

Answer (score 1):

See the accepted answer to this question [Why am I merging "remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop' into develop"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406762/why-am-i-merging-remote-tracking-branch-origin-develop-into-develop)

Where after a long explanation, it suggests add a "git up" alias:

> git config --global alias.up '!git remote update -p; git merge
>   --ff-only @{u}'

So no, it's not a valid command, unless you've installed this alias, which isn't a bad idea.

Comment: If you believe this question is a duplicate, flag it as such. No need to directly answer. Especially not on a 3 year old question.