# Accidentally did git up and then git push

Tags: git, github

I did git up and then git push on my branch. Now, I have all the changes I made plus all the changes everyone else made and so my push includes hundreds of commits.

My understanding is that `git revert [commit number]` lets me undo commits, but then I would have to run that hundreds of times for each of the changes.

Is there a way to undo the whole commit?

Comment: `git up` is not a standard Git command. What is it?

Comment: @Schwern possibly http://aanandprasad.com/git-up/. mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22954983/6309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [git reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset). The third form allows you to set the current branch to a specific commit (where it was before you pulled in everyone else's changes). [Git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) will give you the history of the branch so you can find the commit you want to reset to.