# The git equivalent of "svn status -u" (revisited)

Tags: git, svn

In Subversion, I can see what files would be affected by an update, without actually performing the update, with

```
svn status -u
```

Git doesn not have such a command. The usual suggestion for this problem is to do a fetch first. This is described [here](https://gist.github.com/washingtontimes/333818) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138990/git-equivalent-of-svn-status-u). The latter article also contains a nicely written explanation, why the fetch is necessary.

I stumbled today over a [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231211/using-git-how-do-i-find-changes-between-local-and-remote) of this theme which suggested a different approach, which is to use

```
git pull --dry-run
```

Now this makes me wonder:

1. Does it really work? How can it do it without also doing a fetch?
2. svn pull --help does NOT explain about the --dry-run switch, but if I use it, git does not complain that it is an illegal option either. Is this kind of "undocumented feature"?

Comment: The git documentation is known to have some room for improvement, so it's entirely possible that this option is undocumented. But the option is descibed in the [fetch documetation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick test of `git pull --dry-run` shows that it is equivalent to `git fetch --dry-run`. It doesn't actually fetch anything, it just shows the SHA1s of what would be fetched. This isn't very useful IMHO.

`git pull` is equivalent to `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. Parameters that are valid for either of those commands will normally be passed through, where that makes sense.

If by "an update" you mean `git pull`, then if you split it into the equivalent running `git fetch` and `git merge` commands, you can inspect the state in between to determine what would be merged / fetched. Another option in git is to do the pull, inspect what happens, and undo it if it does something you don't want.

If it has a merge conflict, you can use `git merge --abort`. If it doesn't, you can use `git reset` to put the branch back to the previous SHA1.

Comment: `git pull` tries to pass options it doesn't know to `git fetch` and `git merge`. This means that `git pull --dry-run` is effectively the same as `git fetch --dry-run`.